# Behavior of block elements inside inline elements in list elements in Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox, html-lists

li element containing inline child with a block as inline's child behaves differently in Firefox when compared to chrome.

```html
<h3>Block inside inline </h3>
<div>Block</div>
<div style="display: inline"><div>Block inside inline</div></div>
<h3>Block inside inline in li</h3>
<ul>
  <li><div>Block in li</div></li>
  <li><div style="display: inline"><div>Block inside inline in li</div></div></li> 
</ul>
```

View the snippet in Firefox and Chrome to see the difference. Can anyone explain the reason for this behavior in Firefox?

Comment: That's an edge case if I ever saw one.

Answer (score 0):

`<div>` should not inside `<span>`

Comment: Hi, thanks. I am aware of the practice, I am just curious to know the reason behind the difference in FF when rendered inside a list.